# Autolayout behaving differently on different machines with the same version of XCode

Tags: xcode, autolayout, xcode7.3, ios9.3

We have four machines in the office with the same version of `XCode 7.3 (7D175)` and `OS X El Capitan 10.11.4` (the newest version at the moment of this post). In one of the machines AutoLayout seems to behave differently from the others. Even creating a new project from scratch and doing exactly the same thing, in one of them XCode warns `misplaced views` while the others don't.

Here is a GIF that shows quickly how to reproduce this warning that doesn't happen in the other machines.

[image]

Is there any extra configuration that I should be aware of and check between these machines that may be different and causing such difference?

Already tried to clean out XCode preferences with `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode` and it did clear the settings, but it didn't fix my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out!

It is not a matter of different machines. I have found out that it is a matter of opening the project in monitors with different sizes. If you close XCode and open the same Storyboard in a different monitor (on the same machine) is enough to generate different warnings. The storyboard xml file will get changed just opening the project in another monitor size.

[image: same machine monitor A]

[image: same machine monitor B]

Answer (score 1):

You can try delete your Xcode preferences typing:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Comment: Although this didn't fix my problem, it did clear out the settings. Thanks for the tip, I hadn't tried it yet. I will update my question with this info.